# SQL Error while inserting data into a table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I was trying to execute the following query in Postgres:-

```
INSERT INTO customer_specific_price (id, user_id, model_map_id , start_date  ,
            price_model_id,precedence )
SELECT  coalesce(MAX(csp.id), 0)+1 , cp.user_id, eipm.id , pipt.start_date,
        pipt.price_model_id , pi.precedence
FROM    customer_specific_price csp, customer_price cp, plan_item pi ,
        plan_item_price_timeline pipt , entity_item_price_map eipm
WHERE   cp.plan_item_id = pi.id and pipt.plan_item_id = cp.plan_item_id and 
        pi.plan_id is Null and pi.item_id = eipm.item_id
```

It is giving error

> ERROR:  column "cp.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

When the table did not contain any id column it was working fine. But when I added the id and used `coalesce(MAX(csp.id), 0)+1` its giving the error mentioned above.

Comment: can we format this a little better its very hard to read all of the query when having to scroll right and left.

Comment: Do what the error message said and you've got a lot of other not grouped and not aggregated columns too. This is Postgres, not MySQL with its extension to GROUP BY. Maybe the result will not be as expeced but you should get this SELECT work before you try an INSERT with it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a potential error in your query, this piece:

```
coalesce(MAX(csp.id), 0)+1
```

could potentially place the wrong (unexpected) value in a result row (I didn't check the whole query, plus you didn't show the table structures, so I didn't want to make any other assumption): if the sub-select returns more than one result, then all of them will have the same value for that column.

I guess you want the last `id` from an *autoincrement* column (otherwise you could have id collisions in the destination table if the rows in the source table can be deleted, supposing all those ids are PKs): if that's the case, do not use a group function, but a subquery, like `SELECT id FROM cps ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` (untested, it's just a suggestion).

Apart from that, I think you'll be better rethinking what you are trying to achieve, you then could probably write a different query.

Answer (score 0):

So, when you `added the id and used coalesce(MAX(csp.id), 0)+1`, then you get the error message `ERROR: column "cp.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.` It is because as soon as you introduced an aggregate function (`MAX`, in your case), the other columns are also expected to contain aggregate functions (MAX, SUM, COUNT, etc.) or they should be used for grouping using a `GROUP BY` clause at the end of the query. [Here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/) is a brief tutorial for GROUP BY.

So, your query can be rewritten to group by the other columns, as below:

```
INSERT INTO customer_specific_price (id, user_id, model_map_id , start_date  ,
            price_model_id,precedence )
SELECT  coalesce(MAX(csp.id), 0)+1 , cp.user_id, eipm.id , pipt.start_date,
        pipt.price_model_id , pi.precedence
FROM    customer_specific_price csp, customer_price cp, plan_item pi ,
        plan_item_price_timeline pipt , entity_item_price_map eipm
WHERE   cp.plan_item_id = pi.id and pipt.plan_item_id = cp.plan_item_id and 
        pi.plan_id is Null and pi.item_id = eipm.item_id
GROUP BY cp.user_id, eipm.id, pipt.start_date, pipt.price_model_id, pi.precedence;
```